# QPU On Linux Framebuffer Device

Tags: linux, display, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, gpu, framebuffer

I've been trying to use RPI's DPI driver alongside some logic gates to drive an epaper display.

I've got it working pretty well on the CPU, essentially how it works is that it copies /dev/fb0 i.e. X rendered desktop to /dev/fb1 while also converting all pixels into epaper waveforms.

Now I'm wondering is it somehow possible to use the RPI's QPU unit for processing the waveforms, as only the copy from framebuffer device with the CPU takes about 100ms which is way too slow.

I've tried V3DLib and love it, but can't figure out how to access the fb device without copying data to newly allocated CPU/GPU shared memory. (I hope fb devices use a preallocated part of the GPU mem as the DPI unit is constantly pushing data out of them)

Does anyone know if the QPU could access the framebuffer directly? I've seen that DispmanX can access it, but it doesn't seem to be flexible enough for my purposes.

Thanks in advance!